# Change an excel function into vba code

Tags: vba

I have written 2 Excel functions to copy data to cell `G12` when data is entered in cell `F12`

```
=IF(ISBLANK(F12)," ",(F12))
```

if data in the deleted from cell `G12`  it is copied to `H12`

```
=IF(ISBLANK(G12),(F12)," ")
```

these work perfectly but I was wondering if the same procedure can be carried out in vba on a dynamic range as I want to keep adding rows

Comment: The first formula goes in G12?  If so, the second formula will always return " ", since F12 will never be blank.

Comment: Thanks for response Joe I should have said that the data in G12 may sometimes be deleted to force it to appear in H12

Comment: Ok.  So what will the workflow be? Do you want to run a macro to fill in column G once you're entered all the rows, then another macro to fill in column H once you've deleted some values from G?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your requirements, you can format your range as a table from **Home>Format** as Table. Now, assuming your table as two columns respectively named "name" and "non blank name", you can enter the following formula in the second cell of the second column:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([@Name])," ",[@Name])
```

As you add rows to the table, the formula will be copied automatically to the new row.